# Why does this function return NAN

Tags: javascript

If I use <= instead of <, I'll get NaN, why?

```
function addArgs(){
    var sum = 0, count = 0;

    while(count <= arguments.length){

         sum += arguments[count];
         count++;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: `arguments[count]` is undefined. Adding undefined to 0 = undefined. If you use `<`, the function never evaluates what is in the while block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you iterate through a list and use the index to access the items of the list (like you're doing), you always iterate up to `length - 1` or `< length`. The reason is that the list index starts from zero, not one. For instance, a list of 3 items has it's `length` equals 3 and the indexes of its items are 0, 1, and 2. There is no item with index 3, so if you iterate up to `length` or `<= length`, the counter will reach 3 in the last iteration and the attempt to retrieve the item with the index 3 will fail and return `undefined`.

Finally, adding the `undefined` to the sum will results in a `NaN` because `undefined` is not a number.

Answer (score 3):

in the last iteration of your loop, `count` is `arguments.length`, therefore   `arguments[count] === arguments[arguments.length] === undefined`, and `sum += undefined` results in `sum === NaN`

Answer (score 3):

Suppose your argument is 3 elements:

**arguments = [0, 1, 2]**

Your count will iterate as 0 => 1 => 2 => **3** (and on 3rd you are out of bound of the array, since it has 3 elements, but indexed starting with 0.

That's basics of iterating through loop.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that arguments[count] is not a number (NaN). In Javascript, when the second argument in an expression is not a number, the first one is also treated as not a number.

Thus, sum ends up the function being treated as another data type.

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_datatypes.asp

Answer (score 1):

All iterations start from `0`(Also, `count = 0` in your code). So, max `count` equals `arguments.length-1`.

`addArgs(2,5,8);` -> `arguments[0] = 2; arguments[1] = 5; arguments[2] = 8;`

Besides that, you can use `<=` when `count` starts from `1`

```
function addArgs(){
    var sum = 0, count = 1;

    while(count <= arguments.length){

         sum += arguments[count-1];
         count++;
    }
    return sum;
}
addArgs(2,3,4);//9
```